# $O_p$ notation in asymptotic proof

Tags: statistics, regression, parameter-estimation, economics, time-series

I am currently reading a proof in Pesaran's 2006 paper (Lemma A2 Eq:A11).
There is a quantity $f(N,T):=\frac{F^T\bar{U}_w}{T}$ and the aim is to show that
\begin{align}
f(N,T) = O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{NT}}\right).
\end{align}

They show that $Var(f(N,T)) = O(\frac{1}{NT})$ which would imply $f(N,T)=O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{NT}}\right)$ by Markov. Why dont they stop here and conclude the assertion? They rather argue as follows. 1. $ f(N,T) = O_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}})$ , for fixed T  and 2. $ f(N,T) = O_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}})$, for fixed N. Then they conclude that
$\sqrt{NT} f(N,T) \to O_p(1)$ in distribution which finishes their proof.

Thanks for your expertise in advance.